# How to restore sql database in Private Azure Cloud subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-pack

> I want to restore my database `bacpac` file into `Private Azure Subscription` but I do not get any option in Azure portal :(

Is there any way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 :**
If you have the Database.bacpac file in Azure blob storage you can Export that to  a new Database in the Portal

```
Choose a Database => Configure =>  NewDatabase (New database from Export)
```

or

```
New (Lower left Corner) => DataService => SQL DataBase => Import from Blob
```

**Option2**

If you have your Database.bacpac File in local.
Download and Install [SSSDT (Sql Servert Data Tools)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/tools.aspx)

Connect to your database using SSMS(Sql Server management studio).

then  `Tasks => Deploy Database to SQL Azure` and follow the steps.

Comment: I'm using Private Azure Portal not normal Azure Subscription I do not get any option as shown in Image above :(

Comment: you can try other options like SSDT tool, or creating a new Database from scratch(see Option 1.2) in my answer if availble.

Answer (score 0):

The Import/Export *service* is not available on Private Azure Cloud.

You will need to use SSDT to import into your SQL DB for the Private Azure Cloud Subscription.